# How do I create a MySQL table that contains various collations?

Tags: php, mysql

This is a code to create a MySQL table:

```
$dbcon = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) ;
$q = 
"CREATE TABLE list 
(
fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (fname)
)";
$result = @mysqli_query ($dbcon, $q);
```

The above table doesn't suit my needs because my `fname` input consists of non-latin characters! I get `fname`  values such as `????`.

I've read about "utf8_general_ci" but this addresses to the whole table and and database when I need only one field of that collation to be "utf8_general_ci".

Can someone please give me a code that creates a "multi collations" table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE list 
(
  fname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (fname)
)
```

Take a look at the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html). You can easily change the collation of a single column by using the `COLLATE` keyword, as in the example above.

Each table has a standard collation (usually pre-defined). If you don't specify another collation in the `CREATE` statement, or don't alter your table afterwards, it will fall back to the tables standard collation.